# content_for head tag doesn't work (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" %>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't work.

How to insert html into head tag?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `<%= yield :head %>` inside `head tag` in your `Layout`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have `<%= yield :head %>` inside your `<head>` tag (probably in your layouts/application.html.erb)? No? Then add it :).